# Use jQuery to use value from within a div for a progress bar

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `div` tag which looks like this:

```
<div id="redmine"><%= @value%></div>
```

Using jQuery, how can I get the value from within the div with `id` equal to `redmine` and use that value to show/update a progress bar?

Comment: While your code _does_ include some Ruby on Rails mark-up, I felt that this really didn't need to be tagged using the ruby-on-rails-3 tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve 42 from this example:

```
<div id="redmine">42</div>
```

you would use:

```
parseFloat($("#redmine").html());
```

Of course `parseInt()` could be used instead.

Here is the Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8omd50go/